# How to sort order multiple columns using antd Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, antd, user-experience

I want to display the active sort button on 2 columns of the antd Table. When I click on the "Sort Users" option, the sort button of the "Books" column becomes deactivated.
This is column of table

```
    {
      title: "Book",
      dataIndex: "books",
      sorter: true,
      sortDirections: ["descend"],
    },
    {
      title: "User",
      dataIndex: "user",
      sorter: true,
      sortDirections: ["descend"],
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ROW.png)

How can I display both "Sort Books" and "Sort Users" buttons in an active state at the same time?

Comment: Did you read the [multiple-sorter](https://4x.ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-multiple-sorter)?